# Is there a way to associate an action with a specific exception occurring anywhere?

Tags: java, spring, exception, handler

I am working on a Spring application that throws a specific exception in several places. Is there a way to provide one action (e.g. call a method that sends a warning email) that should always occur whenever such exception is thrown?

Comment: You'll have to be way more specific. How are those several places related? Where in the stack would Spring introduce the handling? Are Spring components even in that stack at that point?

Comment: There are no more specifics, really. The places are not related, I would have mentioned it if it was otherwise. I am not sure what other details I can give you. It's a web service that pulls data from different sources, does some parsing, has some endpoints that return that data in different ways. The exceptions are just several key points in the flow of that data that we want to capture, and I am guessing I can move components around to make that happen. I was hoping to get a general concept that I could read more about and then implement.

Comment: Actually, I am sorry. I think I didn't have enough understanding before. I think it matters that some of the functionality of that application is using a scheduler, with @Scheduled annotation, and doesn't work directly with Response Objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using exception handler. There are quite a few ways to write exception handlers. Some are :

1. Use `@ControllerAdvice` with `@ExceptionHandler`, or
2. extend `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`
   class.

You can look for an example [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2013/02/03/improve-your-spring-rest-api-part-iii/)